# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{[x]+x}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{[x]+x}{x}$, where $[x]$ denotes greatest integer $\leq x$.

We have, if $[x]=k$, then $k\leq x<k+1$.  But I don,t know how to evaluate this. Any hints?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We know the inequality $x-1 < [x] \leq x$, so

$$
\frac{2x - 1}{x} < \frac{[x] + x}{x} \leq \frac{2 x}{x}.
$$

What can you conclude from this?

Comment: Thank you very much. Limiting value is $2$. +1 for you

Comment: @Warrior Not sure why you are not accepting the answer. The acceptance basically "completes" the question and other users don't need to click into the question again.